# Input field upon every input goes out of focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Error occurs under two circumstances:

1. If input has onChange
2. If input is within component that is called on another page

For example:

On `Page1.js` we have:

```
return <div> <Page2 /> </div>
```

On `Page2.js`  we have:

```
const [customState, customSetState] = useState({
   customText: ''
});

return <input value={customState.customText} onChange={setCustomStateText} />

function setCustomStateText(event) {
customSetState({
   ...customState,
   customText: event.target.value
 });
}
```

Error goes away when Page1 is not calling Page2 but just having normal input element, it also goes away once we remove onChange.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your input tag doesn't have closing `/>`. Is that the error?

Comment: My bad, no, this is just quick demonstration on inside the app the actual app returns no errors nothing

Comment: Seems to working fine [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1qlxco). Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: (Also, please declare `setCustomStateText` before the `return` statement. It works because of hoisting but looks really odd.)

Comment: It's like this in example for better readability

Answer (score 1):

I guess your input on each render has been recreated.

What about if you use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook, as the documentation states:

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

Like the following:

```
const inputEl = useRef(null);
const [customState, customSetState] = useState({
   customText: ''
});

return <input ref={inputEl} value={customState.customText} onChange={setCustomStateText} />
```

The other issue what I see there which can cause further issues is not mutating the previous state. I suggest to use as the following:

```
function setCustomStateText(event) {
   customSetState(prevState => {
      return {
         ...prevState,
         customText: event.target.value
      }
   });
}
```

As the documentation states about [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Where would useRef be used? If I use it in onChange function it doesn't focus back on input

Comment: @stacky999 `useRef` should be use similarly like `useState` as you created one in your functional component.

Comment: Even if you use `useRef`, won't the input still be recreated again when the function is executed? I thought mutable object across renders applied only to `useRef(theObjectToBePreserverd)`

Comment: @adiga I guess that's why we have `<input ref={inputEl} />` part in the code so `useRef` will give you the same ref object on every render, if my understanding is correct from: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref. Take a look at the example what they provide but I might be wrong. Maybe one extra needed in the code like `inputEl.current.focus();` needs to be called in the `onChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is with props.children, not the best solution, but it works. If anyone finds better solution let me know. If you set conditional rendering inside component use props.children to set render within another file.